# Characterization of diagonal matrices reducing rank

Tags: linear-algebra

Given full rank matrix $A$. I am looking for a characterization of all diagonal matrices $D$ with
$$
\det(D - A) = 0
$$
This set of rank-reducing matrices is then somehow a superset to the $\lambda I$ used in the eigenvalue equation.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there are a lot of such diagonal matrices. Notice that for any choice of the first $n-1$ elements of the diagonal, there always exists a unique $n$-th entry such that $\det(A-D)=0$.